# Rails - create HBTM scope for filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to create a filter with 2 parameters - one is edited with radio inputs and the other with a group of checkboxes. I have 2 models connected by `has_and_belongs_to_many` association. I neeed to create a `scope` with ids of nested models. For example, I have url:

```
/catalog?category=1&feature=1,2
```

And scope must return the nested instances with `id`s 1 and 2

How can I create scope like that?

My category Model:

```
class Lamp < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :category, inverse_of: :lamps
  has_and_belongs_to_many :features

  validates :name, :preview, :small_preview, presence: true

  scope :visibles, -> { where(hided: false) }
  scope :category_filter, -> (category_id) { where(category_id: category_id) if category_id.present? }


end
```

My feature model:

```
class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :lamps

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :name, uniqueness: true

  mount_uploader :ico, FeatureIcoUploader

  scope :visibles, -> { where(hided: false) }
  scope :ordered, -> { order(prior: :asc, id: :desc) }

  def display_name; name end

end
```

Comment: can you please add the both model?

Comment: @Sunny, added it to my question. Is it enough?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and make sure your middle table name is correct(:features_lamps or lamps_features)

```
Lamp.joins("join features_lamps on lamps.id = features_lamps.page_id").where(["features_lamps.features_id = ?", features_id])
```